# copiar registros de una tabla otra

Tags: php, mysql

Buen Día necesito ayuda por favor

Mi situación es la siguiente:
Tengo 4 tablas

```
tabla_1 (Id, Fecha, Costo, Nombre) 
tabla_2 (Id, Cuidad, Pais, Centro)
tabla_3 (Id, Telefono, Extension)
```

cada una con campos diferentes excepto el id y la

```
tabla_4 (Id, Fecha, Costo, Nombre, Cuidad, Pais, Centro, Telefono, Extension)
```

en donde tengo los campos de las tres tablas anteriores,

para llenar los primeras 4 columnas de la tabla_4 he hecho esto

```
INSERT INTO tabla_4                                                   
(Id, Fecha, Costo, Nombre)
SELECT Id, Fecha, Nombre FROM tabla_1
```

Mi duda es como puedo seguir insertando los registros en las columnas a la tabla_4 en donde el id sea igual en Tabla_2_ y Tabla_4.

Espero y me puedan ayudar, Gracias.
:3

Comment: !Buenas! He visto que Jemonge ya resolvió tu duda, pero igual te dejo aquí esta referencia para que también mires la sintaxis de los Insert, para elegir que campos específicos quieres rellenar: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es un `INSERT` con `INNER JOIN`. Esto te permite realizar consultas uniendo varias tablas e insertar todo junto a la tabla que quieres. Puedes encontrar más información del `INNER JOIN` aquí: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Tu query debería de quedar algo así:

```
INSERT INTO tabla_4                                                   
(Id, Fecha, Costo, Nombre, Ciudad, Pais, Centro, Telefono, Extension)
SELECT Id, Fecha, Costo, Nombre, Ciudad, Pais, Centro, Telefono, Extension
FROM
  tabla_1 t1
  INNER JOIN tabla_2 t2 ON(t1.id = t2.id)
  INNER JOIN tabla_3 t3 ON(t1.id = t3.id)
```